# Sentinel check always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm using Sentinel in my laravel project and am encountering difficulties getting it to work. I set up everything correctly and still

```
Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
return json_encode(Sentinel::check());
```

always returns false, despite the input data being correct. Furthermore, no rows are added to database table `persistences`, which usually is the case. I did some research on the problem, however, none of the questions were actually answered so I hope that here's hope to find this time.

Comment: what is the output of `$result` if you write as `$result = Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());`

Comment: can you show us $request->all()?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got little help from Cartalyst.  I found that my issue originated with the config item 'session' in cartalyst.sentinel.php.  I updated it to 'sentinel' instead of the default 'cartalyst_sentinel'.  Once I reverted this the check worked in a private browser.  I still had the issue in one particular model though.  That issue was with the selected Facade.  You'll need to make sure your use statement points to the Laravel Facade (`use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel`) and not the the Native facade (`use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel`).